# MVC4 FileResult PDF corruption

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am transmitting a PDF to an MVC controller, saving the PDF to a database, and retrieving it.  If I save the PDF to disk on the server side (prior to returning a file result), it looks fine.  However, when I do something akin to the following:

```
    return File(fileBytesFromDB, "application/pdf", "file.pdf");
```

and try to view it from a browser (any browser), the PDF appears to be corrupt.  In fact, it's an entirely different size.

What have I missed?

Comment: This cannot be diagnosed from the information given. Try looking at the network traffic using Fiddler.

Comment: @usr - this wasn't a terribly helpful endeavor as the traffic is a PDF.  It's a file stream, and an encoded one at that.  Passing raw text files seems to work just fine.

Comment: Save the response body. Is it a valid PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.  One of my coworkers had added in a tokenizer as a decorator of return actions, and it was tokenizing the file stream.  I added some logic to ignore `FileStreamResult` and `FileContentResult` and now the PDFs come out okay.

Answer (score 0):

I also found another solution to this. In our DB, our table was storing the filepath, name, mimetype as nchar(255) which is a fixed character count. The added whitespace was not working with the FileResult method even using .Trim(). My particular issue was solved by changing the column to varchar